# 'register' object has no attribute 'get' in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Hi Everyone i make a blog with django but i need to register use and always i get this error:

```
AttributeError at /register/
'register' object has no attribute 'get'
```

i already search too many times but i don't get correct answer so make sure don't mark as a duplicate

Here is my **Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render , get_object_or_404,redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from blog.models import *
from blog.forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)
# Create your views here.\

def user_register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        reg = register(data=request.POST)

        if reg.is_valid():
            user = reg.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

        else:
            print(register.errors)
    else:
        reg = register()
    return render(request,'register.html',{'reg':reg})
```

Here is my **Models.py**

```
class register(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete="Cascade")
```

Here is my **Forms.py**

```
class register(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password')
```

I'm Wating For Your Answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing your`urls.py` file would be helpful, but for the time being I'm going to assume it looks something like this:

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.user_register, name='register'),
]
```

Either way, the issue is that your `user_register` function does not know how to handle GET requests (i.e. when you visit the URL which calls this function). You should define logic within `user_register` to handle a GET request. Something like this:

```py
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        reg = register(data=request.POST)

        if reg.is_valid():
            user = reg.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

        else:
            print(register.errors)

    >if request.method=='GET':
    >    # do something

    return render(request,'register.html',{'reg':reg})
```

Comment: what to do if get?

Comment: Thank You It's working The Fault Is in my urls.py thanks!

Comment: I suggest you read through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/) as it's quite helpful in understanding basic Django functionality.